# Email validation with zod - Multiple error descriptions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, validation, zod

I need to verify the email and the confirm email with zod, and when my refine check if emails don't match i would like to show in both fields my erros, but its not working with `path` in refine.

I'm trying to use `path: ['email', 'confirmEmail']`, but its not working and is giving me an undefined message on form.

```
const SignUpFormInputsSchema = z.object({
    email: z
      .string({
        required_error: 'email is required.',
        invalid_type_error: 'email is invalid.',
      })
      .email('email is invalid.'),
    confirmEmail: z
      .string({
        required_error: 'email confirmation is required.',
        invalid_type_error: 'email confirmation is invalid.',
      })
      .email('email is invalid.'),
  })
  .refine(
    ({ email, confirmEmail }) => {
      return email === confirmEmail
    },
    {
      message: 'emails must match.',
      path: ['email', 'confirmEmail'],
    },
  )
```

Comment: You have a minor typo in your path (`emai => email`).  And you should share what your form solution you're using.

Answer (score 0):

The path should reflect the way you access the erroneous value. What you are doing is trying to access `confirmEmail` of the value `obj.email`. In this case it would be `undefined` because there is nothing in `obj.email.confirmEmail`

The example on the [Zod docs](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod?tab=readme-ov-file#customize-error-path) decides to use the path to the confirmation.

---

Roughly the path can used like this to retrieve a value

```
function retrieveByPath(obj, path) {
    const [key, ...next] = path

    if (next.length === 0) {
        return obj[key]
    } else {
        retrieveByPath(obj[key], next)
    }
}
```